# Conversion from Swift 3.0 to 4

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, macbookpro-touch-bar, nstouchbar

How can I convert my code that I wrote a few years ago to Swift 4.0 without using XCode 10.1? Is there any way to run it on some online simulator or on the newest version of XCode? This is some code that I wrote for messing around and seeing what features the touchbar has. I get this message when I'm trying to open the project.[image: XCode Message]

Comment: Perhaps it’s better to directly convert to the current Swift version instead. Converting it to Swift 4 would only mean it’s obsolete from the start, Swift 5 has been around for quite some time and version 6 is probably not that far away

Comment: Either way, how can I convert my code without using the method I mentioned before?

Comment: If you load your old Swift project into a new version of Xcode, Xcode should offer an option to convert the code to the latest Swift version.

Comment: As written your question is too broad. What kind of code? Which platforms does the app run on? etc. etc. etc. Without XCode, compile your code and fix the warnings and error messages. First, consult the documentation on what changed from 3 -> 4 -> 5. Google search for documents like this: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift4

Comment: @HangarRash it just told me that it was outdated and to update it

Comment: @JohnHanley It's code written for the touchbar. Is there not any online converter or something like that?

Comment: What just told you? And what was outdated and what needs to be updated? Please post clear details instead of vague statements.

Comment: Xcode told me. The code was outdated. It needed to be converted to a later version. I updated the post, so it contains the error message

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any automatic migration tools other than the one that Apple provides in some versions of Xcode. I think your choices here are:

- Use migration assistant in Xcode 10.1 (which is still available from developer.apple.com) to update the code more or less automatically.
- Rewrite the code yourself.

If it's just code for experimenting with the Touch Bar, why not migrate it yourself? There are [lots](https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/from-swift-3-to-4-b094597b889b) [of](https://www.swift.org/migration-guide-swift4/) [resources](https://www.kodeco.com/582-what-s-new-in-swift-4) to help you figure out what you need to change. While you're at it, you might as well move all the way to [Swift 5.7](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/249/whats-new-in-swift-5-7) -- you'll be modernizing both your code and your knowledge of Swift.